# Occurence Frequency Standard deviation

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, standard-deviation

I have a collection of data spread as follows:

Data consists of records of 5 observed numbers from 1 to 90.
On each record the numbers are unique i.e. a record cannot have the same number observed more than once but different records can have the same exact numbers observed.
I have about 50,000 records and i would like to find the standard deviation of the frequency of occurrence of the numbers.

Example data:

```
RECORD1 : 7, 9, 67, 32, 89
RECORD2 : 56, 37, 66, 1, 27
RECORD3 : 1, 7, 54, 48, 90
```

So on and so forth. 
The data is saved in mysql and i preferably would like to use php to present the data but other than the code i would like to know the technique on how to calculate the standard deviation of the occurrence frequency. 
If its possible to be done using only mysql code is much much better and faster.

I am already calculating the frequency as follows by creating the following sql code:

```
$query = "Select ";
    for($_i = 1; $_i < 91; $_i++)
    {
        $query.= "(Select count(*)
    from tbl_occur
    where clm_number_1 = $_i
       or clm_number_2 = $_i
       or clm_number_3 = $_i
       or clm_number_4 = $_i
       or clm_number_5 = $_i) as freq_$_i";
        if ($_i < 91) $query .= ", ";
    }
```

Which will result in the following sql query but of course with the loop i get the frequency of all 90 numbers this is just for number 1

```
Select (Select count(*)
    from tbl_occur
    where clm_number_1 = 1
       or clm_number_2 = 1
       or clm_number_3 = 1
       or clm_number_4 = 1
       or clm_number_5 = 1) as freq_1,
```

Regards,

Comment: What do you want to calculate exactly? Do you want to take all the counts per frequency (e.g. 1:10k times, 2: 9k times, 3: 11k times, ...) and then get the mean/deviation for the values (10k, 9k, 11k, ...)?

Comment: Yes i want the standard deviation of the counts per frequency. From the resulting query i get that 1 occured 5K times, 2 occured 3K times so on and so forth. Now i need the deviation of those values so i can get the nearest five values that are likely to occur

Comment: You say "yes" but your explanation does not fit. The mean/average as I described it would basically calculate how random your numbers occur, e.g. how close your numbers behave like a perfect random (normal) distribution like picking 5 balls out of 90 in a lottery. It won't answer "which number (or numbers?) will occur next". Could you clarify what you want to calculate and add it to your question? Maybe you even know how you could calculate the value you need by hand and only need help doing it in sql? Then add the calculation, e.g. for your 3 sample records.

Comment: Sorry maybe i am not explaining myself correctly in english. But the scenario is similar to the one you just explained, it is like a lottery. I didn't explain myself correctly. I need the calculation on how random numbers occur. I need help on how to calculate it than i can be able to do it in mysql i just want the technique.

Comment: Could you give an example? It does not have to be the correct value(s), but currently I don't even know what kind of result you are after in general, especially since it seems you are actually looking for a technique/concept/idea. Checking if your distribution behaves like a normal random distribution (which is one way to answer "how random your numbers are") is called a [Normality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test); maybe the wiki will give you some ideas what you are trying to implement so you can get more concrete in your question (where we could help again).

Comment: Lets take the lottery scenario. I would like to calculate (i might not have used the correct term) a way to choose the 5 that are most likely to occur on the next record

Comment: For a lottery, you cannot calculate those 5 numbers. To predict 5 non-random numbers (without prior knowledge about how they form), you can use [pattern recognition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) to find rules like "3 records after I got a 10, I always get a 76" or "If I get a 7, I always get a 29 or a 52". With the "standard deviation" you want to calculate here, you could compare it to what it would look like for 50k true lottery numbers; if it's far off, your data might not be random. The Normality tests are more precise in that "might this be random?", but don't predict numbers either.